# How to resize UIView in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have got a main view and a view1 into main view, how to resize view1?

This code doesn't work:

```
self.View1.bounds.size.height = self.view.bounds.size.height;
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
CGRect frame = self.View1.frame;
frame.size.height = self.view.bounds.size.height;
self.View1.frame = frame;
```

Comment: Be careful, though. Stick with either bounds or frame. They are not the same. When rotated into landscape orientation, for example, the frame may still have the original portrait dimensions, but the bounds will always be correct, because the bounds are updated by any transforms applied to the view, including rotation.

Answer (score 5):

You can't modify the bounds directly. The CGRect needs to be modified outside of the view's bounds.

```
CGRect viewBounds = self.view1.bounds;
viewBounds.size.height = self.view.bounds.size.height;
self.view1.bounds = viewBounds;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to add a simple comment to some of the other answers, so I'll help point out a couple of important points here:

(1) If just changing the size, set new `bounds` instead of `frame`

If you are *just* looking to resize an image (but keep the image at the same location), then follow *cdownie's suggestion* of setting new `bounds` instead of a new `frame`. For example, if you have an image of a pointer hand and want to make it look as if it's tapping the screen, then scaling the size of the `bounds` down and back up real quick will achieve that and it will maintain its same screen location at its center point if you set the anchor point of the image at its center. If you had changed the `frame` instead as Tony Friz suggested, then upon a reduction of image size, the image will pull to its top-left corner (unless you correct for that with extra math).

(2) If the image created in nib or storyboard, turn off Autolayout and Autosizing

Autolayout needs to be turned OFF over any views in which you are moving images around or resizing them. If you leave it on, the behavior will (of course) be odd and unpredictable. Also, with Autolayout off, go into the image's Size Inspector and set the proper origin (center, for example) and disable all Autosizing constraints by clicking on any solid lines in the Autosizing grid until all of them are dotted lines. This way you will have full control over image placement by altering the `center` property and sizing by setting new `bounds`.

Hope this helps,
Erik

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.View1 setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```